# event.getSource is not a function

Tags: lightning-button

When trying to get a button's value on lightning component controller, I'm getting the following error:

> event.getSource is not a function

This is the code on the component side:

```
<lightning:button label="Select this"
     onclick="{!c.buttonClicked}" value="{!object}"/>
```

This is the code on the controller side

```
buttonClicked : function(component, event, helper){
    let selectedButton = event.getSource();
}
```

Any tips? Component is on v42.0, which I guess should mean LockerService is active. I'm pretty sure I've used this syntax with lightning:button before.

Thanks in advance.

***Edit:***

This is working fine in another component

Component

```
<lightning:button label="Select" value="{!acc}" onclick="{!c.selectAccount}" />
```

Controller

```
selectAccount: function(component, event, helper){
    var selectedAccount = event.getSource().get("v.value");
    component.set("v.selectedAccount", selectedAccount);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad, my bad... I had an outer div (from previous experiments) also handling onclick with {!c.buttonClicked}. That's what was generating the error, the event was being captured twice and standard html tags lightning doesn't support event.getSource()